# Java - Moving file from Explorer to Java GUI - what kind of event is that?

Tags: java, user-interface, explorer

I would like to move files from the Windows Explorer to my Java GUI and act on that event by receiving the path of the file(s) to upload it(them) to a server.

What kind of event is that? Where can I find some information about it (example code?) ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about [drag and drop (DnD) events](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html). And here's a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/dnd.aspx) that does Windows <-> Java app DnD.

Comment: +1. Tested this recently. File drag and dropping and other types of information works well. You can extend `javax.swing.TransferHandler`, override the importData method and iterate through the transfer data to handle a list of files. You can then apply an instance of your custom `TransferHandler` to a component via the `setTransferHandler` method. It'd be nice to know if it's possible to set this in one go for more than one `Component`.